# Kill a Process Started via a the Eclipse Remote Systems Feature

Tags: windows, eclipse, process, dos

I'm trying to make some use of Remote Systems in Eclipse. This is what I did:

1. Click to Window > Show View > Other... from the Eclipse menu bar.
   The Show View dialog appears.
2. Select Remote Systems and press OK
   The system opens the Remote Shell tab in your workspace.
3. Rich click on Local Shells and select Launch Shell.
4. Started a process in the shell --- normally I can terminate this with CTRL-C at the DOS prompt.

There is no way to kill this process int he Local Shell. If I terminate the shell the process keeps running. I can kill the process by restarting Eclipse but that defeats the purpose.

I can run a shell by configuring an external tool, but I was hoping to use this nifty Remote Systems feature if I could.

Anyone got a work around?

Comment: Would a command-line tool for killing processes, such as taskkill or pskill, help?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution when working with a particular process type (like NodeJS or Mongo) on Windows (could be adapted to other OS).

You can kill the process with the command line:

taskkill /im node.exe /f

So, set this up as a Remote Systems User Action (both Folder and File) by right-clicking in Remote Systems view and selecting User Action > Work with User Actions. Then any time you need you can right-click in the Remote Systems view and select your User Action to kill the process. I found an Eclipse restart was necessary after setting it up.